# Can I use my Samsung SM-J700P on the ATT network?

Tags: samsung, sim-unlocking, att, sprint

It was locked to the Boost Mobile network (Sprint) before I supposedly unlocked it with Odin, but using the ATT SIM card says it's not supported for the device.  I've spoken to both companies and neither seems to be able to help.
Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between unlocking a phone and rooting a phone. What ODIN can do is root a phone (giving you unrestricted access to the features and settings), what you need to do is unlock the phone (allowing you to change the cellular settings).

Once that's done, you need to set the cellular settings for the AT&T network (they would currently be set to the BOOST network). AT&T technical support is who should be able to help you with that, but the phone needs to be unlocked first.

Comment: Thank you, but then how would I unlock it?  Since I thought I did that according to a youtube guide I followed.  And sorry for the late reply. I thought no one answered my post earlier on...

Comment: Boost can unlock it, usually for a fee. There's websites that do this also, usually for a smaller fee.

Comment: @user253978 What YouTube guide have you been following?

Comment: Well my family spoke to both companies and an ATT rep told them that the phone is too old a model and can’t be used on their network.  Is this true though?  Since supposedly my phone can be used on CDMA and GSM networks and I don’t fully take the store reps word.  As for the YouTube guide, I forget exactly which one it was, but I know they asked me to use Odin.  Also, why do I have to pay for an unlock code?  Is there any other means to obtain one from a program or another way? Thanks again.

Comment: @user253978 I have 2 phones that are way older than yours, and they work fine on modern networks. As for unlocking fees, unless you know somebody who works for the carrier it's locked to or that carrier has a policy of unlocking phones for free once the contract is up, you would have to pay. The unlock codes are stored in a private database, some websites have privileged access, and they charge for that. It's probably $15.

Comment: Do you know any reputable sites for unlock codes?  Thank you again for your help tlhIngan and God Bless you! :D

Comment: @user253978 That falls under "shopping recommendation," which is off-topic on this site. But the last site I used for unlocking was <cough> it was called <cough cough> cell unlocker <cough>, and it was on the "net" <cough cough>.